# How to find eigenvalues of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a question from our end-semester exam:

> How to find the eigenvalues of the given matrix:

M=\begin{bmatrix}
5,1,1,1,1,1\\
1,5,1,1,1,1\\
1,1,5,1,1,1\\
1,1,1,5,1,1\\
1,1,1,1,4,0\\
1,1,1,1,0,4\\
\end{bmatrix}

I know that $4$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ with multiplicity atleast $3$ since $M-4I$ has $4$ identical rows.

Is there any way to find all eigenvalues of this matrix? I could find only $3$ out of $6$.

Comment: Obviously the multiplicity of eigenvalue $4$ is $4$ since the rank of $M-4I$ equals $2$. So if you've found two more, you're done.

Comment: To add to the previous comment if we know 4 out of 6 eigenvalues, then we also know sum and product of the remaining two eigenvalues. (Since trace is the sum of all eigenvalues and determinant is their product.) However, in this specific case, probably calculating determinant is not much easier than calculating the characteristic polynomial. So it is not that much of simplification. (Still, checking that the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to trace after we finish computation is a good sanity check.)

Comment: Since you had several additional questions, I will just add that a good place for discussing posts (questions, answers) might be the [Linear & Abstract Algebra chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13473) - at least if you use chat. You can find some other interesting chatrooms here: [List of chatrooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814).

Answer (score 3):

For [block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix), you can use [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Schur_complement):
$$0=\det(M-I\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix}A&B\\ C&D\end{vmatrix}=\det(D)\cdot \det(A-B\cdot D^{-1}\cdot C)= \\
\begin{vmatrix}4-\lambda&0\\ 0&4-\lambda\end{vmatrix}\cdot \det\left(A-B\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\frac1{4-\lambda}&0\\ 0&\frac1{4-\lambda}\end{pmatrix}\cdot C\right)=\\
\small(4-\lambda)^2\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}5-\lambda&1&1&1\\ 1&5-\lambda&1&1\\ 1&1&5-\lambda&1\\ 1&1&1&5-\lambda\end{pmatrix}-\frac2{4-\lambda}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\right)=\\
\small\frac1{(4-\lambda)^2}\cdot \det\begin{pmatrix}\lambda^2-9\lambda+18&2-\lambda&2-\lambda&2-\lambda\\ 2-\lambda&\lambda^2-9\lambda+18&2-\lambda&2-\lambda\\ 2-\lambda&2-\lambda&\lambda^2-9\lambda+18&2-\lambda\\ 2-\lambda&2-\lambda&2-\lambda&\lambda^2-9\lambda+18\end{pmatrix}=\\
\small \frac{\lambda^2-12\lambda+24}{(4-\lambda)^2}\cdot \det\small{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\ 2-\lambda&\lambda^2-9\lambda+18&2-\lambda&2-\lambda\\ 2-\lambda&2-\lambda&\lambda^2-9\lambda+18&2-\lambda\\ 2-\lambda&2-\lambda&2-\lambda&\lambda^2-9\lambda+18\lambda\end{pmatrix}}=\\
\small\frac{\lambda^2-12\lambda+24}{(4-\lambda)^2}\cdot\det\small{\begin{pmatrix}\lambda^2-8\lambda+16&0&0\\ 0&\lambda^2-8\lambda+16&0\\ 0&0&\lambda^2-8\lambda+16\end{pmatrix}}=\\
\frac{\lambda^2-12\lambda+24}{(4-\lambda)^2}\cdot (4-\lambda)^6=0 \Rightarrow \\
(4-\lambda)^4\cdot (\lambda^2-12\lambda+24)=0\Rightarrow \\
\lambda_{1,2,3,4}=4, \lambda_{5,6}=2(3\pm \sqrt{3}).$$

Comment: I don't get how you did the step  "$(4-\lambda)^2 \det()...$ to $(4-\lambda)^2 (\lambda^2-12\lambda+24) \det().....$ .

Comment: How did you take out the factor $(\lambda^2-12\lambda+24)$

Comment: @Math_Freak If you add the other rows to the first row (i.e., you get sum of all rows in the first one), then each entry in that row is equal to $\lambda^2-12\lambda+24$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak; Thank you very much, But I dont understand the next step too

Comment: @MartinSleziak;How does the $4\times 4$ matrix get reduced to  a  $3\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: @Math_Freak After adding $(\lambda-2)$-multiple of the first row to the other rows, you get one and three zeroes in the first column. Then you can do Laplace expansion w.r.t. the first column.

Comment: @MartinSleziak; i am extremely thankful for clearing all my doubts

Comment: I also thank you Martin for answering the questions. I tried to keep the answer as short as possible leaving out some basic (to me, at least) steps of row operations. Good luck.

Comment: @farruhota; I have another question . How do you know that $\det(D)=\det(xI-4I)$ is not zero?

Comment: @MartinSleziak ;I have another question . How do you know that $\det(D)=\det(xI-4I)$ is not zero?

Comment: In fact, we want to find for what values of $\lambda$ (or $x$ in your above case) it will be zero.

Comment: As an analogy, consider the equation $x^3+2x^2-3x=0$. We can write is as $x\cdot \left[\frac1x \cdot (x^3+2x^2-3x)\right]=0$ or $x(x^2+2x-3)=0$.

Comment: @farruhota; so the Schur complement formula can always be used irrespective of whether $\det D$  is zero or not?

Comment: @Math_Freak You get $\det(D)=0$ only for $\lambda=4$. It's not difficult to check the case $\lambda=4$ separately and to see that the equality $\det(M-\lambda I)=(4-\lambda)^4(\lambda^2-12\lambda+24)$ is true in this case, too.

Comment: @MartinSleziak; my question is can we use Schur complement formula even when $D$ is not invertible

Comment: It depends. $\begin{vmatrix}\color{red}A&B\\C&D\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\color{red}1&2\\3&0\end{vmatrix}=-6\ne 0$, but $\begin{vmatrix}\color{red}A&B\\C&D\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\color{red}2&\color{red}3&1&1\\\color{red}4&\color{red}5&1&1\\ 1&1&2&3\\ 1&1&4&6\end{vmatrix}=\det(D)\cdot \det(A-B\cdot D^{-1}\cdot C)=0$, where $D^{-1}$ must be treated as [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse). In this problem we did not actually calculate the determinant of $D$ numerically, we transformed it algebraically to get final answer, which is free of singularity.

Comment: @Math_Freak I left some comments about this [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13473/2019/9/9) - so that I do not create too long comment thread here. (It is rather long already.)

Comment: Though, in the first case, by the generalized inverse it will work too (looks strange): $$\begin{vmatrix}\color{red}A&B\\C&D\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\color{red}1&2\\3&0\end{vmatrix}=0\cdot \det(\color{red}1-2\cdot \frac10 \cdot 3)=0\cdot \det(\frac{0-6}{0})=0\cdot \frac{-6}{0}=-6.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=(1,1,1,1,0,0)^T$ and $y=(0,0,0,0,1,1)^T$. Then
$$
M=4I+(x+y)(x+y)^T-yy^T=4I+xx^T+xy^T+yx^T.
$$
Since $x\perp y$, $M$ is orthogonally similar to
$$
4I+\|x\|^2e_1e_1^T+\|x\|\|y\|(e_1e_2^T+e_2e_1^T)=4I+\left(\begin{bmatrix}4&\sqrt{8}\\ \sqrt{8}&0\end{bmatrix}\oplus0\right).
$$
Hence the spectrum of $M$ is
$$
4+\{2+\sqrt{12},\ 2-\sqrt{12},0,0,0,0\}=\{6+\sqrt{12},\ 6-\sqrt{12},4,4,4,4\}.
$$
**Edit.** The characteristic polynomial of $M$ over $\mathbb R$ is thus $p(x)=(x-4)^4(x^2-12x+24)$. As $\mathbb Z$ is a subring of $\mathbb R$, the characteristic polynomial over $\mathbb Z$ is also $p$. If the entries of $M$ are taken from a general commutative ring $R$ instead, since there is a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $R$, the characteristic polynomial of $M$ over $R$ is still $p$.

Answer (score 3):

Let us try to find the determinant of the matrix.
$$M-\lambda I=
\begin{pmatrix}
  5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We will use the fact that adding multiple of one row to another one does not change the determinant.

$\det(M-\lambda I)=
\begin{vmatrix}
  5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
  4-\lambda & \lambda-4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=\dots=
(4-\lambda)^3\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4-\lambda & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)^3\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4-\lambda & \lambda-4 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)^4\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)^4\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)^4\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 & 1 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-1 \\
  0 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)^4\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 3 & 5-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-1 \\
  0 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)^4\begin{vmatrix}
  1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 &-1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 8-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)^4\begin{vmatrix}
 8-\lambda & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 &-1 \\
 4 & 0 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}=
(4-\lambda)^4
[(8-\lambda)(4-\lambda)-4-4]=
(4-\lambda)^4(\lambda^2-12\lambda+24)
$

Comment: +1. While writing my answer I was wondering if it was simpler than merely calculating the determinant by row operations. Seeing your answer I still doubt about which method is simpler.